# How to increase LDAP data limit

Tags: c#, ldap

Am getting the full list of users (~80k number of records) and getting "The size limit was exceeded" error (only first 1000 records are fetched)
What is the way to bring large number of records?

````
SearchRequest searchRequest = new
       (userStore,
       "(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))",
       SearchScope.Subtree,
       new string[] { "department", "manager", "mobile" });

var response = (SearchResponse)_connection.SendRequest(searchRequest);```
````

Comment: which provider are you using?

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.Protocols

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP query limit is usually set with domain policies. It could be increased, but it's not necessary as you can get your full results by using   Paged Results Control with `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` and limiting it to e.g. 900 each.

```cs
//your search
SearchRequest request = new
       (userStore,
       "(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))",
       SearchScope.Subtree,
       new string[] { "department", "manager", "mobile" });

PageResultRequestControl pageRequestControl = new PageResultRequestControl(900); // 900 entries per page

request.Controls.Add(pageRequestControl);

while (true)
{
    SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);

    PageResultResponseControl pageResponseControl = (PageResultResponseControl)response.Controls[0];

    // the current page
    foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in response.Entries)
    {
        //process your stuff...
    }

    // check if there are more pages
    if (pageResponseControl.Cookie.Length == 0)
        break;

    // this is afaik optional...
    pageRequestControl.Cookie = pageResponseControl.Cookie;
}
```